# Civicrm 4.7.20 Register event participant - pay by creditcard

Tags: civievent

just updated to civicrm 4.7.20 - I wanted to register a late event participant used Register Event Participant in the past.  I can select the event and price but if I check 'record payment' the payment block with CC #, ccv and expiry doesn't come up. I did this once and seemed to get the Contact info page plus a link to enter credit card information. 
What is the correct way to get the payment block (not just the priceset for the event) to come up?

Comment: FYI when I test in the sandbox and select credit-card payment I only get a box for 'last 4 digits' of the card - but I want to submit  the  actual payment, full CC number, CCV and expiry.  How can I record a credit-card payment for an event on behalf of an attendee?

Comment: Hi Lesley - are you able to either Accept Karin's answer, or add your own and Accept that so this can be closed off

Answer (score 1):

From a Contact's summary page -> hit the Events tab

[image]

-> then hit the Submit Credit Card Event Registration button - and select an Event. If it's a paid event and you've got a Payment Processor setup/selected that handles Credit Cards - then the Credit Card fields will appear:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, KarinG, I had tried this from just Reg.Event Part w/existing contact. When I tried this from the Sandbox (which I assume you did here) it worked as you showed.

Comment: Excellent - glad I could help you out.

Comment: hmm, it seems like if I have several payment processors defined and set one as a 'default', there's no dropdown for payment processor AND the credit card info block isn't shown. If I go into Admin/Payment Processors and make none of them the default, the dropdown for pay.processor shows and then I get the CC info block.

Comment: In the sandbox there's only 1 pay. processor (Test) and you can't add any there. seems like a bug - I can try fixing it.